# What are the elements of $\Pi_0$ on a topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, path-connected

Since a set is disconnected if and only if there are non trivial clopen sets, are those clopen sets exactly the distinct path components?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve has no nontrivial clopen sets, but it has two different path components.

Comment: Also, even if we forget path connectedness, the regular connected components need not be clopen - consider $\mathbb Q$, or a Cantor set, in which the connected components are points, which are not clopen as the points are not isolated.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!